# Extractor error code -777 when using design automation

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I am trying to complete a full runthrough of the Forge API for an inventor model. We have succesfully managed to submit the workitem which does everything it needs to do based on our personalised appbundles and activities.

The issue is when the new model is trying to be loaded in the viewer with the URN for the SVF which is in the newly created output bucket.

I am getting a translation error and I cannot figure out where the error is coming from or how to fix it.

- Is the translation not automatically completed when the SVF is created for export, which is the point of using this activity i thought?
- Is it the CreateSVF activity which is not zipping it correctly?

Any suggestions from anyone on where to look if this is an obvious one, can't find the same error online.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

There is some weird thing Inventor is doing in exported SVF for use in ForgeViewer. It looks like bubble.json is not at the level it is needed to have it. You can see how we are doing the export in our demo application. After export done by Inventor, we move bubble.json to different place. See https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-configurator-inventor/blob/master/AppBundles/CreateSVFPlugin/CreateSvfAutomation.cs#L101

Comment: Thanks @Michael, but having looked at the CreateSvfAutomation.cs file, i have the identical code.  So i don't think it is that...
Hopefully there is another explanation out there that someone can help with.

Comment: Can you share URN that generated ? -777 is Internal Translation error, bubble is expected but not created.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, there is no URN, because translation happens on FDA outside of the Model Derivative Services.
Also reading your question again. We are not using URN for the zip inside the bucket. You have to download and unzip the file containing SVF and then host it so all files are available for browser. Then you use address of bubble.json to load using https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-configurator-inventor/blob/master/WebApplication/ClientApp/src/components/forgeView.js#L89

Comment: Thanks @MichalVasicek, i will try that solution.